# ExecuteReader not returning all records returned by stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using `ExecuteReader` of `Microsoft.Practices.EnterprizeLibrary` to fetch data from database. the store procedure that i have created returning two records but the `ExecuteReader` giving me one record. i am confused why it is happening. i am using following line of code.

```
public List<Products> GetProductsData(Products p)
    {

        List<Products> productList = new List<Products>();
        using (IDataReader rdr = dbt.ExecuteReader("pGetProducts",p.productType))
        while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Products obj= new Products();
                {
                    obj.Id = Common.CheckIntegerNull(rdr["id"]);
                    obj.AId = Common.CheckIntegerNull(rdr["aid"]);
                    obj.Name = Common.CheckStringNull(rdr["name"]);
                    obj.Price = Common.CheckDecimalNull(rdr["amt"]);

                }
                productList.Add(obj);
            }
        return productList;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please paste your code as a **text**, not as an image..

Comment: Please post the SP as well.

Answer (score 2):

To consume all the result sets of an execution you need to call [`NextResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult.aspx) until it returns false.

```
public List<Products> GetProductsData(Products p)
{

    List<Products> productList = new List<Products>();
    using (IDataReader rdr = dbt.ExecuteReader("pGetProducts",p.productType))
    {
       do
       {
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
            Products obj= new Products();
            {
                obj.Id = Common.CheckIntegerNull(rdr["id"]);
                obj.AId = Common.CheckIntegerNull(rdr["aid"]);
                obj.Name = Common.CheckStringNull(rdr["name"]);
                obj.Price = Common.CheckDecimalNull(rdr["amt"]);

            }
            productList.Add(obj);
          }
        } while (rdr.NextResult());
      return productList;
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to make a new picture; just use Photoshop on the one in the question :)

Comment: @W0lf: you know, I wast *this* close to do it, but of course using GIMP ;)

Comment: ??  `reader.Read()` should normally do it. I see no indication of multiple sets.

Comment: The only place we could see an indication of multiple result sets would be in the stored procedure code, which was not posted. In lack of more information, the simplest explanation is that the SP is returning multiple result sets.